# Java Inheritance and late binding, why does int id have the parent class value and not the child class one?

Tags: java, inheritance

Determine the output:

```
public class Test1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
        c.print();
    }
}

class ParentClass{
    int id = 1;
    void print(){
       System.out.println(id);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    int id = 2;
}
```

I know that the answer is 1, and I'm guessing that it's because since the print function isn't overridden in the `ChildClass`, it has the same definition as it has in the `ParentClass`. Why isn't the ID the one given in child class since Java uses late binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only version of the `print` method is in the `Parent` class, and it only has visibility on `Parent`'s `id` field.

In order to print the `Child`'s id, you'd have to `@Override` the `print` method using the exact same idiom, which would print `Child`'s id if present, when invoked on an instance of `Child`, or `Parent`'s `id` field if visible and no `id` has been declared in `Child`.

**Example**

If you add this code to your `ChildClass`:

```
void print() {
   System.out.println(id);
}
```

Either `ChildClass` declares `int id = 2` as it does now, and any invocation of `print` on a `ChildClass` instance will print `2`.

Or, `ChildClass` does not declare `id` and `print` will print `1` provided `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` are in the same package (your `id` field is default-access in `ParentClass`).

Comment: @drossy11 you're welcome. Also take a look at other answers (more theoretical but worth considering): the gist being fields are *hidden*, methods are *overridden*.

Comment: Quick question, if there was a hello() function defined in the parentClass that was overridden in childClass(), and there was a call for the hello() function in the constructor of class parentClass() it would use the hello() class defined in the childClass() because there is dynamic dispatch on methods, right?

Comment: @drossy11 yep exactly. Virtual method invocation in action: your overridden method will be invoked where implemented (e.g. in `Child`), even if invoked from the parent constructor, as long as the instance is a `Child`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no dynamic dispatch on object fields, only on methods.

Comment: Instead there is [`hiding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e12172).

Comment: Quick question, if there was a hello() function defined in the parentClass that was overridden in childClass(), and there was a call for the hello() function in the constructor of class parentClass() it would use the hello() class defined in the childClass() because there is dynamic dispatch on methods, right?

Answer (score 2):

Because the second `id` field declaration is **hiding** the first one, not *overriding* it.

Class `ChildClass` has *two* fields named `id`, each accessible as `super.id` and `this.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Make id protected in parent, then change the value in child constructor.

Comment: Making id protected in parent does not change the value of output. It's still 1 due to "hiding" or "shadowing" effect of parent class

Comment: I would disagree. The child can change the value in the constructor and it will persist across the class, unless the parent changes it.